# In VSCode, how to open local files without using a dialog but just by typing and Tab-complete？

Tags: visual-studio-code, user-experience, tab-completion

I was so used to the way of opening a file in Emacs, by just C-x C-f and typing and tab-completing, without needing to use a mouse. In VS Code, I have to go through a "open file" system dialogue using a mouse to find my file. But when opening a file in SSH server, VS Code offers a built-in dialogue to find your file, by just typing and auto-complete. Is there a way to use the "open SSH file" dialogue to open local files, or a similar way by just typing and tab complete?

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+P`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following setting in your JSON config:

```
"files.simpleDialog.enable": true
```

This does not open the native file browser for local files. Instead, you can search for them in the same manner as you would do for remote files:

[image: local file picker]