# How to select the open option while opeing a folder in vscode

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When i want to open an folder in vs code l do Ctrl K + Ctrl O then the file picker pops up but the problem is i dont to how to chose a file using keyboard like i want to open a folder named XYZ so if i press enter it opens the folder not open the folder in vscode.

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJfWu.png)

I want to know which keyboard shortcut should i click to get the result i get by clicking on the blue open button on top right. (i have tried ctrl + enter, ctrl + space not working) I use Fedora 40

Comment: Unsure how it works on linux - but if you press enter one the folder you have selected does that not work? Can you also press the tab key to navigate around the dialog controls?

Comment: voted to close as "not about programming". this is about your OS / desktop environment's file explorer application- not about VS Code. unless you want https://stackoverflow.com/q/70267366/11107541